# State is undefined after POST request

Tags: reactjs

Using to create a CRUD phonebook. Using JSON server as my pretend database.

When I create new data it is successfully added to my database. However at that moment I get the error of state is undefined. When I refresh the DOM it displays fine.

My create functionality looks like this.

```js
  const createContact = async contactObject => {
    await fetch('http://localhost:3001/phonebook', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(contactObject),
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    });
  };

  const contactObject = {
    name: newName,
    number: newNumber,
    date: new Date().toISOString(),
  };

  createContact(contactObject).then(res => setPersons(persons.concat(res)));
```

Initial state

```js
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([])

  const getAllContacts = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/phonebook')
    const data = await res.json()
    return data
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllContacts().then(response => setPersons(response))
  }, [])
```

New data is adding to my database correctly `onSubmit`

```json
{
  "phonebook": [
    {
      "name": "hello",
      "number": "111",
      "date": "2020-10-29T03:02:44.604Z",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "world",
      "number": "222",
      "date": "2020-10-29T03:16:00.725Z",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried to make it so React doesn't render state unless it is available. In my render component

```js
export const ContactList = ({ persons }) => {
  return persons.length ? (
    <ul>
      {persons.map(person => (
        <Contact key={person.id} person={person} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  ) : (
    <h1>Loading contacts</h1>
  );
};
```

I thought this would not try to list persons until they are available however it is still giving me `persons.id` is undefined error.

First time doing CRUD so I'm unfamiliar with how React responds to this.

Comment: You don’t return anything from the fetch-containing method.

Comment: In addition to what Dave wrote, use functional updates when updating state, e.g. `setPersons(prev => prev.concat(res))`.

Answer (score 0):

Need to return something from function

```js
 const createContact = async (contactObject) => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/phonebook', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(contactObject),
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
    })
    const data = await res.json()
    return data
```

Also when updating state, functional updates are required

```js
.then(data => setPersons(persons => persons.concat(data)))
```